# Default <supports-screen> tag Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android App, and I'm creating some folders for supporting multiple devices.
But my question is, what is the default `<supports-screen>` tag in AndroidManifest?
If I don't write the tag, what devices will support? All? Just the folders that I created, for an example.." layout-ldpi,layout-mdpi", and my app will support just this densities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will support all devices with minimum SDK which you set in your Manifest. 
From Android Developer site:

To optimize your application's UI for the different screen sizes and densities, you can provide alternative resources for any of the generalized sizes and densities. Typically, you should provide alternative layouts for some of the different screen sizes and alternative bitmap images for different screen densities. At runtime, the system uses the appropriate resources for your application, based on the generalized size or density of the current device screen.

**You do not need to provide alternative resources for every combination of screen size and density.** The system provides robust compatibility features that can handle most of the work of rendering your application on any device screen, provided that you've implemented your UI using techniques that allow it to gracefully resize (as described in the Best Practices, below).

Check the full guide on Supporting Multiple Screens 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

By default, your application would run on all devices across densities. If you create resources with specific resolution, while the application is run on the those devices, respective images would be rendered on the screen.

For example - Your application has ldpi folder only.

Scenario 1 - your application running on ldpi device. The images in ldpi folder would be rendered on screen.

Scenario 2 - Your application running on hdpi device. Since your application does not contain hdpi resources, the available ldpi resources would be rendered on screen (but it would be stretched/shrinken which would not look good)

Hope this answers your question.